# Order df columns according to a target vector (but the names match only partially)

Tags: r, matrix, vector, columnsorting

I have a **data.frame (PC)** that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWJKe.png

which has 1000+ columns with similar names.

And I have a **vector of those column names** that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQ48u.png

I want to sort the columns (beginning with "GTEX.") in the data.frame such that they are ordered by the age indicated in the **age matrix**.

```
PC <- read.csv("protein_coding.csv")
age <- read.table("Annotations_SubjectPhenotypes_DS.txt")
```

I started by changing the names in the **age matrix** to replace the '-' by '.':

```
new_SUBJID <- gsub("-", ".", age$SUBJID, fixed = TRUE)
age[, "SUBJID"] <- new_SUBJID
```

Then, I ordered the row names (SUBJUD) of the **age matrix** by age:

```
sort.age <- with(age,  age[order(AGE) , ])
sort.age <- na.omit(sort.age)
```

I then created a vector *age.ID* containing the SUBJIDs in the right order (= how I want to order the columns from the **PC matrix**).

```
age.id <- sort.age$SUBJID
```

But then I am blocked since the names on the **PC matrix** and the **age matrix** are not the same... Could someone please help me?

Thank you very much in advance! 
Svalf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been better to show the example without using an image.  Suppose, if there are two strings,

```
str1 <- c('GTEX.N7MS.0007.SM.2D7W1', 'GTEX.PFPP.0007.SM.2D8W1', 'GTEX.N7MS.0008.SM.4E3J1') 
str2 <- c('GTEX.N7MS', 'GTEX.PFPP')
```

representing the column names of 'PC' and the 'SUBJID' column of 'age' dataset (after replacing the `-` with `.` and `sort`ed), we remove the suffix part by matching the `.` followed by 4 digits (`\\d{4}`) followed by one or more characters to the end of the string (`.*$`) and replace it by `''`.

```
 str1N <- sub('\\.\\d{4}.*$', '', str1)

str1[order(match(str1N, str2))]
#[1] "GTEX.N7MS.0007.SM.2D7W1" "GTEX.N7MS.0008.SM.4E3J1"
#[3] "GTEX.PFPP.0007.SM.2D8W1"
```